# How to get entry of a dictionary from vmware_guest_disk_facts

Tags: json, ansible, yaml, vmware

I'm trying to get the datastore name for a specific hard disk but I haven't been successful in being able to figuring out choose an entry in the list.

This output is from the ansible module "vmware_guest_disk_facts"
I save this output to a variable called "vm_info".

```
   "guest_disk_facts": {
        "0": {
            "backing_filename": "stuffstuff",
            "capacity_in_kb": 106954752,
            "backing_eagerlyscrub": false,
            "backing_datastore": "WHAT I REALLY WANT",
            "backing_writethrough": false,
            "label": "Hard disk 1",
            "backing_type": "FlatVer2",
            "key": 2000,
            "capacity_in_bytes": 109521666048,
            "backing_thinprovisioned": false,
            "controller_key": 1000,
            "summary": "106,954,752 KB",
            "unit_number": 0,
            "backing_uuid": "info"
        },
        "1": {
            "backing_filename": "stuffstuff",
            "capacity_in_kb": 15728640,
            "backing_eagerlyscrub": false,
            "backing_datastore": "DON'T CARE OF ABOUT THIS ONE",
            "backing_writethrough": false,
            "label": "Hard disk 2",
            "backing_type": "FlatVer2",
            "key": 2001,
            "capacity_in_bytes": 16106127360,
            "backing_thinprovisioned": false,
            "controller_key": 1000,
            "summary": "15,728,640 KB",
            "unit_number": 1,
            "backing_uuid": "info"
        }

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.guest_disk_facts | json_query(query) }}"
      with_items: "{{ vm_info.results }}"
      vars:
        query: "guest_disk_facts.0.backing_datastore" #done w/ & w/o quotes around 0
```

I've also tried the following queries and I feel like I've exhausted all options at this point.

```
    query: "guest_disk_facts.[0].backing_datastore"#done w/ & w/o quotes around 0

    query: "guest_disk_facts[0].backing_datastore" #done w/ & w/o quotes around 0

    query: "guest_disk_facts.*.backing_datastore" #will give me backing_datastore entries for both dictionaries in this case
```

I would like to just get backing_datastore for one entry in this list of dictionaries

msg: "WHAT I REALLY WANT"

but so far I'm returned with either this error:

Expecting: ['quoted_identifier', 'unquoted_identifier', 'lbracket', 'lbrace'], got: number: Parse error at column 17, token \"0\" (NUMBER), for expression

OR

msg: ""

OR

msg:[

"0",

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The task below gives "WHAT YOU REALLY WANT"

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ guest_disk_facts['0'|quote].backing_datastore }}"
```

The point is quoting the quoted key. The keys '0' and '1' are not [valid variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#creating-valid-variable-names) and must be quoted.

The loop below

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ guest_disk_facts[item|quote].backing_datastore }}"
  loop: "{{ guest_disk_facts.keys() }}"
```

gives

```
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => 
  msg: DON'T CARE OF ABOUT THIS ONE
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => 
  msg: WHAT I REALLY WANT
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely works for this.
If I were to use variable instead of a number would it be something like this?


        - debug:
             msg: "{{ guest_disk_facts[item|quote].backing_datastore }]"
           with_item: "{{ variable_to_use }}"

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you're right. `[item|quote]` works fine. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this -

```
  - name: Get all disks from existing VM
    vmware_guest_disk_info:
      validate_certs: False
      hostname: '{{ vcenter_hostname }}'
      username: '{{ vcenter_username }}'
      password: '{{ vcenter_password }}'
      datacenter: Asia-Datacenter1
      name: VM_8046
    register: existing_disk

  - name: Get Backing datastore for desired disk id
    set_fact:
      disk_zero_datastore: "{{ item.value.backing_datastore }}"
    with_dict: "{{ existing_disk.guest_disk_info }}"
    when: item.key == '0'

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ disk_zero_datastore }}"
    when: disk_zero_datastore is defined
```

Comment: thanks for posting this, it worked for what I was trying to solve in my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526787/ansible-extract-string-from-playbook-json-output-and-register-as-a-variable?noredirect=1#comment112346137_63526787