# Ansible: Extract string from playbook json output and register as a variable

Tags: json, ansible, ansible-2.x

Using Ansible 2.9.10

Ran a playbook to store the vmware_guest_disk_info into a variable called disk_info.

```
      vmware_guest_disk_info: 
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
        datacenter: "{{ dc }}"
        name: "{{ vm_name }}"
      register: disk_info
      delegate_to: localhost
```

I am trying to extract the value, EEE-EEE-EEEE-033, from key: backing_datastore. I need to register the value as a variable to use as a variable further in playbook.

```
{
                    "hosts": {
                        "localhost": {
                            "_ansible_delegated_vars": {},
                            "_ansible_no_log": false,
                            "action": "vmware_guest_disk_info",
                            "changed": false,
                            "guest_disk_info": {
                                "0": {
                                    "backing_datastore": "EEE-EEE-EEEE-033",
                                    "backing_eagerlyscrub": true,
                                    "backing_filename": "[EEE-EEE-EEEE-033] 
                                       serverhostname/serverhostname.vmdk",
                                    "label": "Hard disk 1",
                                    "summary": "62,914,560 KB",
                                    "unit_number": 0
                                }
                            },
```

I tried using loops, json_query, look ups, subelements, but I am not too experienced with these yet.

```
- name: get datastore 
    loop: "{{ hosts | json_query('localhost.guest_disk_info[*].backing_datastore') }}"
  register: ds_result
  delegate_to: localhost
```

```
    - name: get backing_datastore value from the variable'disk_info'
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('vars', 'disk_info')}}"
      vars: 
        disk_info: "{{ disk_info }}"
      debug: msg="{{ disk_info.json | json_query(jmesquery)}}"
      vars: 
        jmesquery: "[*].backing_datastore"
```

Updated code:

```
- name: extract backing_datastore value from variable "disk_info"
  debug: var=disk_info.hosts.localhost.guest_disk_info.0.backing_datastore
  register: ds
  delegate_to: localhost 
    
- name: show me variable ds contents
  debug: var= ds
```

error received:

```
"disk_info.hosts.localhost.guest_disk_info.0.backing_datastore": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'hosts'"
```

Comment: For this specific topic, I suggest you have a look at [Accessing complex variable data](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#accessing-complex-variable-data). If you only need the specific data your mentioned, you can find it in `{{ disk_info.hosts.localhost.guest_disk_info.0.backing_datastore }}`

Comment: I read article and see how to get {{ disk_info.hosts.localhost.guest_disk_info.0.backing_datastore }}. what ansible task would be able to extract that?

Comment: `- debug: var=disk_info.hosts.localhost.guest_disk_info.0.backing_datastore` for one...

Comment: Don't spread info needed to answer your question over comments. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63526787/edit) instead.

Comment: Isn't the example data you pasted in your question a debug of your registered var `disk_info` ?

Comment: No, the example data in the question is from running my playbook using vmware_guest_disk_info module. what is proper command to use to extract backing_datastore value?

Comment: So what about looking at the exact structure of the var you are gathering ? `- debug: var=disk_info`.

Comment: Tried ```- debug: var=disk_info```, and I get same output as from  ```- debug: var=disk_info.hosts.localhost.guest_disk_info.0.backing_datastore```. Only different was the variable of ds showing the block of code.